# Error on DataTemplate DataTypes when going from 2012 to 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

In an attempt to resolve some WPF problems I've been having, and still have unresolved questions on, I got permission to go from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2015. The solution is still using the 3.5 Framework (I will upgrade later). Going from 2012 to 2015 seems to have made the overall XAML work better, but now I have a stack of errors that didn't exist when it was in 2012. It is on components that I did not engineer, and I have not made modifications to.

I was able to fix the DataTrigger errors by changing around how the value was checked.

But, I can't figure out how to resolve the `DataTemplate` errors regarding the `DataType`. I have searched all over, and nothing is helping.

1. **The type reference cannot find a public type named '*SomePublicEnum*'** : The assembly is still in the namespaces of the affected items (UserControl, ResourceDictionary, etc). The enums are all declared within the namespace as `public enum SomePublicEnum`. An example DataTemplate opening that is giving the error is `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:OrderLifetime}" x:Key="OrderLifetimeDataTemplate">`.
2. **The type reference cannot find a public type named '*SomeInterface*'** : Again, nothing changed from 2012 to 2015. The namespace is there, and the interface is public. In fact, this particular declaration is directly below the `OrderLifetime` enum mentioned above. The template: `<DataTemplate x:Key="TradeDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type model:IPTOrder}">`.
3. **The type reference cannot find a public type named '*SomeAbstractClass*'** : Also in the same namespace as the above ones. In this case, it's a `public abstract class`. The template: `<DataTemplate x:Key="InstrumentTemplate" DataType="{x:Type model:Instrument}">`.

I did notice that if I type `model:`, it only gives me one static class as the auto-complete. I don't know why it's doing that, either. Unfortunately, this isn't a simple matter of designer versus runtime. It won't compile at all whereas it did in VS2012. I have to remove the `DataType` to make it compile.

**QUESTION: Do any of you have any ideas about 1 through 3 above?**

**UPDATE 5/19:** This is still not working. I'd like to be able to put the `DataType` back.

Comment: The thing I really don't understand is that the `DataType` syntax hasn't changed. I've searched all around, and it looks fine. For enums, it's using a converter to display something else in a TextBox based on the value. The interface and abstract class are just used for binding other classes that implement/inherit those. These are the 3 errors that are keeping me from compiling the 2015 solution and continuing with what I was trying to do. >:(

Comment: For now, I just removed the `DataType` from all of them. I don't know if it will have any effect down the road, but I've managed to get past other errors and get it to compile and run.